# How do I paint all of my objects in collection to different colors via python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, color, collections

I want every object in my collection to have different color. 
How do I make it via python scripting?

Comment: I assume you are talking about a different color in the material for every object?

Comment: @David yes, how do I make it?